# SVG animateTransform reverse rotate

Tags: svg, rotation, reverse

having this

http://codepen.io/ssstofff/pen/CamJd

It's rotating on the upper left corner, and the animation is reversing.
But I want to  have to rotation on the right bottom axis

This works when you replace the 'values' with 'from to'.
But then, I do not have the reverse effect anymore.

Till now, can't figure out how to establish the rotating on bottom right corner + the reverse effect.

Thx a lot for your help!
Stof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
values="0;10;0"
```

use:

```
values="0 550 450;10 550 450;0 550 450"
```