# How to set an origin point for svg's animateTransform

Tags: animation, svg

If you view this SVG, I'm animating the transform property, and it moves from the top left by default. How do I change it to animate from the center instead?

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
  <rect width="400" height="400" fill="#495ade"/>
  <g>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="#49de7d"/>
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                    type="scale"
                    values="1 1;.5 .5;1 1"
                    begin="0s"
                    dur="1.5s"
                    repeatCount="indefinite"
                    calcMode="spline"
                    keySplines="0.4 0 0.5 1; 0.5 0 0.5 1"
                />
  </g>
</svg>
```

**What I tried already:**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22303262/svg-animatetransform-reverse-rotate) says to just throw X & Y coords after each of the values listed. So I tried `values="1 1 50 50;.5 .5 50 50;1 1 50 50"` but that kills the animation.

You can also use `from` and `to` instead of `values`, and include an X & Y origin, but I need 3 animation states, not two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the animation `animateTransform type =" scale "`, you can use the animation of increasing the radius of the circle

In this case, it will not be necessary to define the `transform-origin` since the circle is in the center of the canvas.

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
  <rect width="400" height="400" fill="#495ade"/>
  <g>
  <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="50" fill="#49de7d">
  <animate attributeName="r"
                    values="50;25;50"
                    begin="0s"
                    dur="1.5s"
                    repeatCount="indefinite"
                    calcMode="spline"
                    keySplines="0.4 0 0.5 1; 0.5 0 0.5 1"
                /> 
    </circle>           
  </g>
</svg>
```

*Pause animation in intermediate states*

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
  <rect width="400" height="400" fill="#495ade"/>
  <g>
  <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="50" fill="#49de7d">
  <animate attributeName="r"
                    values="50;25;25;50;50"
                    begin="0s"
                    dur="1.5s"
                    repeatCount="indefinite"               
                /> 
    </circle>           
  </g>
</svg>
```

## Update

Consider Implementing CSS Animations

```css
#crc1 {
transform-origin:center;
transform-box:fill-box;
animation: scale 1.5s infinite;
}

@keyframes scale {
0%{transform:scale(1);}
50%{transform:scale(.5);}
100%{transform:scale(1);}
}
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
  <rect width="400" height="400" fill="#495ade"/>
  <g>
  <circle id="crc1" cx="200" cy="200" r="50" fill="#49de7d"/>
   </g>
</svg>
```

**Upd2**

*SMIL animation*

On excellent advice from **@Sphinxxx**, add css rules to the group tag, thus keeping the `animateTransform SVG`

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
  <rect width="400" height="400" fill="#495ade"/>
  <g style="transform-origin: center; transform-box: fill-box;">
  <circle  cx="200" cy="200" r="50" fill="#49de7d"/>
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                    type="scale"
                    values="1 1;.5 .5;1 1"
                    begin="0s"
                    dur="1.5s"
                    repeatCount="indefinite"
                    calcMode="spline"
                    keySplines="0.4 0 0.5 1; 0.5 0 0.5 1"
                />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Hi @alexandr_tt - Thank you, you are definitely correct However, my circle demo was a simplified case... in the real thing I'm building, I need to use transformation, and I need to define the center of it, so that's why I was specifically asking for that in my question

Comment: @kthornbloom I will try to change my answer according to your conditions

Comment: @kthornbloom See new additions to the answer

Comment: You can also combine the two: As long as you specify `transform-origin` and `transform-box:fill-box`, you can keep the <animateTransform>:  
`<g style="transform-origin: center; transform-box: fill-box;">...`

Comment: @Sphinxxx Thanks for the advice!

Comment: I'm disappointed in you, SVG! No transform-origin is crazy. @alexander_tt, this gets me close enough, I'll accept as the best solution in lieu of an origin.

Comment: @kthornbloom Here is the same `origin` is set in the styles inside the SVG **style="transform-origin: center; transform-box: fill-box;"**

Comment: You're a legend @Alexandr_TT your origin through styles is the secret ingredient that has helped me out yet again.

Answer (score 1):

- It's easiest to have the circle at the origin, that way the scale works from its centre.
- Then we need to translate the `<g>` element instead so the circle appears at the same place.
- Finally we need to actually animate the circle and not the `<g>` element by wrapping the animateTransform by the `<circle>` element.

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
  <rect width="400" height="400" fill="#495ade"/>
  <g transform="translate(50, 50)">
  <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="50" fill="#49de7d">
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                    type="scale"
                    values="1 1;.5 .5;1 1"
                    begin="0s"
                    dur="1.5s"
                    repeatCount="indefinite"
                    calcMode="spline"
                    keySplines="0.4 0 0.5 1; 0.5 0 0.5 1"
                />
    </circle>
  </g>
</svg>
```

- Alternatively we could transform the circle itself and then use additive="sum" to apply the transform animation on top.

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
  <rect width="400" height="400" fill="#495ade"/>
  <g>
  <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="50" fill="#49de7d"  transform="translate(50, 50)">
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                    type="scale"
                    values="1 1;.5 .5;1 1"
                    begin="0s"
                    dur="1.5s"
                    repeatCount="indefinite"
                    calcMode="spline"
                    keySplines="0.4 0 0.5 1; 0.5 0 0.5 1"
                    additive="sum"
                />
    </circle>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll explore this. It sure seems like there should be a way to set the origin like you can during a rotation though.

Comment: There is not, unfortunately. This is one of SVG's more charming features.

Comment: @MichaelMullany - You can set the origin with CSS properties. See [Alexandr_TT's updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66446170/1869660)

Comment: That doesn't work cross-browser. Try it in iOS Safari.